# Newsletter Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I am trying to send the newsletter to the subscribers in Magento 1 but the newsletter is not sent I applied all the process for sending a newsletter but it doesn't send.

Comment: can you please provide more information to understand what type of issues you're facing to send newsletter withing Magento 1 backend.

Comment: Are other emails working? like orders and signup email?

Comment: orders and sign up and ... etc are fine Except sending the newsletter when I made it and I put the date and I save it then it doesnot go to the sebscribers and in the Statu I see ( Not sent) what do think is the reasen

Comment: Please set the newslatter email temaplet to default, there should be something wrong with that, or is there any other module which your are using for email related features?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these below step:

1- Check if Magento cron is running by looking into cron_schedule table. There should be resent records for newsletter queue listed in the table and status of the module execution.

2- Run cron service manually by pointing your browser to http://your.magento.url.here/cron.php

3- Enable PHP mail log: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log

4- Check outgoing mail queue on the server with the mailq command